# read an excel file

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

In my asp.net dynamic data project I want to read an excel file using suitable Microsoft technology (Not Excel).
Someone said their was a server side tool for this?
I want to read the first few columns of data from a table?

Any suggestions or directions on where to go?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=reading+excel+asp.net&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC Have you first tried searching?

Comment: NPOI is a good open source tool for XLS file formats.  But agreed, do a quick search.

Comment: yeah searching atm, I just thought someone with experience on a task such as this might be able to share what they have used?

Comment: @Anonymous found a few OLEBD, plus a few others, but im looing for something which is easy to use with asp.net

Comment: @John I'm use OleDb for a process in asp.net. It takes an excel sheet, loops through and saves each row from the excel sheet into an xml file. I started to write it up as a blog/reminder but never finished it. http://wp.qbressler.com/?p=48 The process isnt too bad.

Comment: specifically looking for server side tools for reading xlsx files, all i can find are tutorials on OLEBD. please help

Comment: @Anonymous thanks for that it looks promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to your comments, take a look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37055/Working-with-MS-Excel-xls-xlsx-Using-MDAC-and-Oled

Here is some (untested) code to get you started.

```
string connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                          Data Source=c:\\testexcel.xls;
                          Extended Properties\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
using(conObj = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
{
   using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableScript, conObj)
   {
      OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      adpt.Fill(ds,"w1");
   }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this Codeplex Project called **Excel Data Reader**:

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can take use of OLEDB object or you can take use of Interop object to read each cell from excel file and insert it in database
see below code snippet
in following snippet i have used OLEDB and fetch the values from excel

```
string objCON = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=EXcel_file_path;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'"
using(OleDbConnection objCon = new OleDbConnection(objCON))
{
    objCon.Open();
    OleDbCommand objCMD = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", objCon) 
    using(OleDbDataReader objDR = objCMD.ExecuteReader())
    {
         while(objDR.Read())
         {
             messageBox.Show("value of row1 and column 0" + dr[0]);
         }
        if(objDR != null)
        {
    objDR.Close();
    objDR = null;
         }
    }
}
```